# Remove automatic naming of variables in visualizations in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have two columns with dates and daily currency observations. In a chart, the default title looks like this:

[image]

If you change the valuetype to Average like this:
[image]

Then the title changes as well:

[image]

Is there any way to override this functionality?
There is a suggestion on [community.powerbi.com](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/change-name-table-visual-average-of/m-p/61481#M25245) to add another measure with the desired name, but that is not a very feasible solution when you have a lot of variables.

Thank you for any suggestions!

**Edit** in response to a comment below where @user5226582 correctly points out that the title can be easily edited. Here's another example with two variables and **labels** in addition to a title:

[image]

The title, as you pointed out, can easily be changed here:

[image]

So that we end up with this:

[image]

However, the problem  with the automatic addition of **Average of...** still persist in the legend:

[image]

And as far as i can tell you don't have the same felxibility with the legend as you do with the title:

[image]

Comment: Go to "Visualisations" pane -> "Format" tab (paintbrush icon) -> expand "Title" -> change "Title Text" value.

Comment: You are right! But the problem still persists with the labels when there are more variables. Any idea how to change those as well?

Comment: "problem still persists with the labels when there are more variables" - can you please elaborate on that? When I add a visual and override the title, it remains unchanged even if I include more variables/measures.

Comment: Thanks. Now I see what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the July release of Power BI Desktop, you can now rename fields in visuals. The field will be renamed anywhere it is used in a chart.

[Power BI Blog](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-july-feature-summary-2/#rename)

Comment: Thank you for the tip! This looks great.

Answer (score 2):

The solution, as mentioned in your question, is to define a measure. That way, you can name it whatever makes the most sense.

You mention that it's not very feasible to create measures when you have a lot of variables, but I'm not aware of a fixed limit. You don't have to create a measure for everything: you could just create measures for numbers you want to average, for example. Personally, I recommend measures for all the main metrics. I usually hide the underlying columns, so no-one is confused.

There are a few benefits of using measures (in no particular order):

- You can name a measure whatever you want since the measure is not coupled to the underlying column
- You can change the definition of a measure at any time and it will update everywhere (e.g. change it to average a different column, for example)
- You don't have to switch from 'sum' to 'average' every time you use the measure, as you've pre-defined it
- There's no risk you use the wrong type of aggregation (e.g. sum when you don't intend to)
- You can define a specific format (number of decimal places, thousands separator, etc), which can vary from the underlying column. Further, you can standardize that format for that measure, saving you having to apply the format every time you use it
- You can use simple measures (sums and averages) as building blocks in more complex measures, making those more complex measures easier to read, along with all the benefits of being able to change the underlying base measure definition should you ever need to

It might sound silly that you'd ever want to change the definition of a basic averaging measure, but such things can happen and it's a pain if you have to update a dozen or more charts & visuals & complex measures to make the change.

I'm sure there are other benefits I'm not thinking of too, but in general, using measures isn't something to avoid. Quite the opposite: measures are the foundation of advanced modeling in Power BI.

Comment: Thank you for a very enlightening answer! I wrestled with these things a bit yesterday, making a bunch of new measures with more fitting names. And, the very same day, Power BI includes a brand new functionality in its latest release where you can rename fields in visuals. But as you said, measures are the way to go in most other regards in Power BI, so it was definitely not a waste of time.